# $g(x-y) = g(x)g(y) +f(x)f(y), f(0)= 0$

Tags: functions

Suppose the non-constant functions $f$ and $g$ satisfy the following two  conditions:

$1)\ g(x-y) = g(x)g(y) +f(x)f(y)$

$2)\ f(0) = 0$.

Determine  $g(0)$ and $(f(x))^2 + (g(x))^2.$

Is the answer $g(0) = 0?$ Is the second answer $0?$

Answer (score 4):

I am supposing that $f$ and $g$ are real functions. \ 
For $x = y = 0$ we have  $g(0) = g(0) ^ 2$ then $g(0) = 0$ or $g(0) = 1$ but if $g(0) = 0$ we have $g(x)^2 + f(x) ^ 2 = g(0) = 0$ which implies $f = g = 0$ since $f,g$ are non constants we have $g(0) = g(x) ^ 2 + f(x) ^ 2 = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=y=0$. Then $$g(0)=[g(0)]^2+[f(0)]^2\\g(0)=0 \text{ or } 1$$
Let $x=y$. Then $$g(0)=[g(x)]^2+[f(x)]^2$$

Suppose $g(0)=0$.

Taking $y=0$, we get $$g(x)=0$$ But $g$ is non-constant. Therefore, $$g(0) \neq 0$$ Hence, $$g(0)=[g(x)]^2+[f(x)]^2=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Put $x=0$ and $y=0$ into the relation,

$$g(0-0)=g(0)g(0)+f(0)f(0)$$

$$g(0)=(g(0))^2+0$$

$$g(0)=0  ,  1$$

Assume $g(0)=1$ , we get $f+g=0 $ but $f$ and $g$ are non-constant

So $g(0)=0$

Also,

$$(f(x))^2 + (g(x))^2$$

$$=g(x-x)=g(0)$$

Answer (score 1):

Putting $x=y$ in the first relation, note that $g(0)=g^2(x)+f^2(x)$. Also, $g(0)=g^2(0)+f^2(0)\implies g(0)=0,1$. But $g(0)=0\implies f(x)=0,g(x)=0$, which contradicts the fact that they are non-constant. So, $g(0)=1$.